# Curl urls in PHP?

Tags: php, string, curl

I am trying to do some curl'ing from PHP

I have:

```
$url="http://sites.target.com/site/en/spot/mobile_fiats_results.jsp?_DARGS=/site/en/spot/mobile_fiats.jsp&asin=&dpci=".$arriPadSKU[$counter]."&zipcode=".$vZip."&city=&state=";

$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL, '$url');
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);

curl_close($curl_handle);
```

$url produces a URL like this and it works in a browser:

`http://sites.target.com/site/en/spot/mobile_fiats_results.jsp?_DARGS=/site/en/spot/mobile_fiats.jsp&asin=&dpci=057-10-1830&zipcode=95128&city=&state=`

However I dont seem to get results from my Curl call, I dont think any results are returned. If I look though the results in $buffer I dont see the data like I do on the page.

Can I not set a $url like this to CURLOPT_URL?

How would I structure this From a command line this works:

`echo "iPad 2 Wi-Fi White 16GB: "; curl -s --data "_dyncharset=ISO-8859-1&asin=&dpci=057-10-1839&zipcode=95128&city=&state=" http://sites.target.com/site/en/spot/mobile_fiats_results.jsp?_DARGS=/site/en/spot/mobile_fiats.jsp`

Comment: Have you tried urlencode()'ing that url?

Comment: you didn't pass url correctly
use double quotes or dont use them at all

$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL, "$url");

Comment: ok, so curl executes but I get back an error page versus results

Comment: paste the link I am trying in a browser and it works! CURL doesn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're enclosing $url in string literal 's.

If you run curl_getinfo($curl_handle); you'll see the url it's requesting is http://$url which is obviously not valid.

```
Array
(
[url] => http://$url
[content_type] => 
[http_code] => 0
[header_size] => 0
[request_size] => 0
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 0
[namelookup_time] => 0
[connect_time] => 0
[pretransfer_time] => 0
[size_upload] => 0
[size_download] => 0
[speed_download] => 0
[speed_upload] => 0
[download_content_length] => -1
[upload_content_length] => -1
[starttransfer_time] => 0
[redirect_time] => 0
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )
)
```

**EDIT**

Here is the updated code I'm using to test:

```
<?php

$url="http://sites.target.com/site/en/spot/mobile_fiats_results.jsp?_DARGS=/site/en/spot/mobile_fiats.jsp&asin=&dpci=057-10-1830&zipcode=95128&city=&state=";

$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
//curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);

//curl_close($curl_handle);

print $buffer."\n";

print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_handle));
?>
```

This works for me. However, the only other problem I see that could prevent you from receiving data back is your insanely low connection timeout. Try setting it higher.

Again, the above code does work.

**UPDATED AGAIN**

The reason you're recieving an error back is because the target site checks for a valid user agent.

Something like:

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.15) Gecko/20110303 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.15");
```

works just fine.

Comment: @vicTrolla, I trued just `$url` (vs `'$url'`) and I dont think it works either

Comment: @vicTrolla, I actually tried `'$url'` when `$url` did not seem to work

Comment: @Tomd Updated my answer once again to account for the error page you're discussing in the comment section above.

Comment: @vicTROLLA - in the sake of learning, how did you know that they checked for a valid user agent?

Comment: @Tomd Through trial an error. I have experience writing web crawlers and find, increasingly, that sites are checking user agents for various reasons. Off the top of my head, they may check user agent to determine whether the request is originating from a mobile browser versus a desktop browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

instead of

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL, '$url');
```